# Getting unable to upload iApp Hosted Content

Tags: ios, objective-c, in-app-purchase

"
I am trying to upload iApp Hosted content via Application Loader.The current version of my live app is 3.0.The version of Hosting Content  is 1.0 ,which i want to deliver with a new INApp Purchase for my application's new version which will(4.0).
After export content from Xcode ,when i tried to deliver content from Application Loader ,validation got successful,but after validation i am getting following error.

ERROR ITMS-2000: "Version '3.0', Locale 'pt-BR': keywords cannot be edited in the current state" at Software/SoftwareMetadata/SoftwareVersion
        ERROR ITMS-2000: "Version '3.0', Locale 'zh-Hans': keywords cannot be edited in the current state" at Software/SoftwareMetadata/SoftwareVersion

Please help me to solve the problem
"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if the keywords of your app in iTunes Connect has comma(,) at the end of keyword string.

For Instance:
"key1,key2,key3,key4,key5,"

[Image: keyword in iTC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DYtgp.jpg)

That comma next to "key5" cause the error.

We denote the iTunes Connect as iTC below.

To avoid this error, please try as follows:

1) Create newer bundle version in iTC 
(we assume it to be 3.1 here).

2) Edit key word to "key1,key2,key3,key4,key5" then save. (We removed comma next to key5)

3) Start the Application Loader, and select IAP-box.

4) Select your App.

5) In the management screen, select the new IAP item, 
   and set the content package (.pkg file)

6) Application Loader's File menu -> Save (Command+S) this project to some .itmsp file, and quit Application Loader.

7) In the finder, right crick on that .itmsp file or control+crick on it.

8) Select "show package content" in the displayed menu.

9) You can see "metadata.xml" in the Finder. 
   Open it with text editor you like.

10) You can find that there is the structure as below:

[Image: version elements in xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mwu9e.jpg)

11) Remove the area marked with red box.

12) Save the file and quit text editor.

13) Open the .itmsp file with Application Loader.

14) Try delivery.

This metadata.xml includes the information about not only IAP meta data but also your app's meta data. And the problem comes from mismatch between the metadata in xml and that in iTC. That is the keywords in the xml has only 5 in "key1,...,key5,", but iTC recognize there are 6 keywords.

Keywords are written inside the keywords-tag in the xml.

I was sorry about the language in screen shots are Japanese language.